# How to select records not contained in a list of tuples with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am working with sqlalchemy v1.4, trying to select records from a table (as defined by a list of columns) that are not contained in a list of python tuples. I've tried various combinations of `values` and `._exclude`, but I hit errors when working with more than one column. For example, `select(["*"]).select_from(values(...).data(...))._exclude(select(...))` works with one column but complains about a mismatch in number of columns when I'm working with multiple columns. I think this is because `["*"]` only has one element. I have not found a way to select explicit columns from a `values` object. That might solve the problem.

Is there a canonical way to do this?